# Create an ERD Diagram from a case study

Tags: database, erd

The case study is:

Maps systems is a company that specialises in shipping and intends 
to have up-to-date information on the processing and current 
location of each shipped item. To do this, Maps systems 
relies on a company-wide information system. Shipped items are the 
core of maps product tracking information system. Shipped items are
characterised by item number (unique), weight, dimensions, insurance
amount, destination, and final delivery date. Shipped items are 
received into the Maps system at a single retail center. Retail 
centers are characterised by their type, uniqueID, and address. 
Shipped items make their way to their destination via one or more 
standard Maps transportation events (i.e., flights, truck 
deliveries).These transportation events are characterised by a unique   scheduleNumber, a type (e.g., flight, truck), and a deliveryRoute.

What I managed to complete:

```
shipped_items                         retail_centre     
item_number (Pk)                      retail_id (PK)          
weight                      N:1       retail_type            
dimensions              ---------     address                
insurance_amount
destination
final_delivery_date                         |
        |                                   |
        |                                   |
        |                                   |
        |                                   |
        |                                   |
        |              transport_event      |
        |              schedule_id          |
         ------------  transport_type-------
      N:M              address              1:N
```

However they lecture say we aren't allowed to have many to many relationships and thats when I begin to stumble. I thought about adding an order_item attribute with the entities item_number, schedule_id, and address. Please Help!

Comment: Use [`juntion table`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) to avoid N:M relationships

Comment: Are my relationships correct?

Answer (score 0):

Nice try. First of all I think there shouldn't be any relationship between transport_event and retail_centre according to the business case. You can convert a many-to-many(N:M) relationship to two one-to-many (1:N) by creating a bridge entity between the two. This bridge entity say "path" for example will inherit the primary keys of the participating entities(shipping_item,transportation_event) in the relationship as foreign keys.

You can have **path**(**pathID**,*item_number*,*scheduleNumber*,origin,destination)

The italicized attributes are the foreign keys. So **path** will be the many side of both relationships as it can combine any two shipped items and transportation events more than once.

Hope it helps.